# Распознавание рукописного текста с фотографии с использованием flutter и keras

Tags: python, flutter, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Мне нужно написать приложение, с помощью которого пользователь мог бы воспользовавшись камерой телефона, сфотографировать, например, тетрадь и сохранить текст с фотографии в документ. Я решил использовать Flutter, т.к. лучше всего его знаю.
Для распознавания текста с фотографии я пришёл к выводу, что нужно использовать свёрточную нейросеть, обучил её, на данный момент у меня есть нейросеть, которая принимает на вход фотографию с каким-то определённым словом и на выход выдаёт это слово в виде строки.
У меня два вопроса:

1. оптимально ли такое использование нейросети, может стоит изменить подход?
2. если ответ на первый вопрос да, то как сделать так, чтобы при наличии фотографии с кучей рукописных предложений я мог разделять их на фотографии с одним словом и подавать их на вход нейросети? Причём насколько я понял важно учитывать то, что у меня программа и нейросеть будет запускаться на Flutter из под Tflite

Comment: Делят картинку на отдельные фрагменты тоже с помощью нейросетей обычно. Но они другие чем те, которыми распознают. То есть две нейросети нужно.

Comment: @CrazyElf а какой должна быть это сеть? Свёрточной? И если да, то как её обучить именно обрезать фотографию? Может у вас есть какой-то пример?

Comment: Гуглите по словосочетанию "нейронные сети сегментация изображений". Хотя не уверен, что 100% подойдёт, но по идее это сегментация, то, что вы хотите сделать перед распознаванием.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, это почти то, что мне нужно, но я не могу найти именно про сегментацию текста с фотографий, то есть опять же мне нужно разбивать фотографию на отдельные слова или символы, но как это сделать не понимаю.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал такие вопросы задавать в специализированном сообществе ods.ai, тут вам вряд ли кто-то с этим поможет, и я тоже настолько эту область не знаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf понял, спасибо за наводку

Comment: Хм, только у них на сайте пропала ссылка на их slack, непонятно теперь, где же все их сообщества искать. Да и вообще сайт какой-то полурабочий сейчас. Непонятно.